# GTK Entry Completion not only by prefix

Tags: gtk3

I've been using the Gtk Entry Completion widget to show suggestions not only based on prefix as-you-type but all substrings that matches the search term, but the widget not behaves well, because it expects prefix matching (like select with arrow keys, show the inline completion, etc..)
Is there an easy way to support that or need I to create other widget that supports the search by substrings?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it using the api and the rest services (not glade files). It looks like a glade bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`gtk_entry_completion_set_match_func()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntryCompletion.html#gtk-entry-completion-set-match-func).

> ```
> void
> gtk_entry_completion_set_match_func (GtkEntryCompletion *completion,
>                                      GtkEntryCompletionMatchFunc func,
>                                      gpointer func_data,
>                                      GDestroyNotify func_notify);
> ```
>
> Sets the match function for `completion` to be `func` . The match
>   function is used to determine if a row should or should not be in the
>   completion list.
>
> Parameters
>
> - `completion`: a GtkEntryCompletion
> - `func`: the GtkEntryCompletionMatchFunc to use
> - `func_data`: user data for `func`
> - `func_notify`: destroy notify for `func_data`.

Here, `func` is a boolean function that should return `TRUE` if a row is to be displayed, and `FALSE` otherwise.

> ```
> gboolean
> (*GtkEntryCompletionMatchFunc) (GtkEntryCompletion *completion,
>                                 const gchar *key,
>                                 GtkTreeIter *iter,
>                                 gpointer user_data);
> ```
>
> A function which decides whether the row indicated by `iter` matches a
>   given `key`, and should be displayed as a possible completion for
>   `key`. Note that `key` is normalized and case-folded (see
>   `g_utf8_normalize()` and `g_utf8_casefold()`). If this is not
>   appropriate, match functions have access to the unmodified key via
>   `gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (gtk_entry_completion_get_entry()))`.
>
> Parameters
>
> - `completion`: the GtkEntryCompletion
> - `key`: the string to match, normalized and case-folded
> - `iter`: a GtkTreeIter indicating the row to match
> - `user_data`: user data given to `gtk_entry_completion_set_match_func()`       Returns
>
> `TRUE` if `iter` should be displayed as a possible completion for
>   `key`

---

I have tested this using the following short (and very poorly written) code:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

gboolean func(GtkEntryCompletion *completion,
              const gchar *key,
              GtkTreeIter *iter,
              gpointer user_data) {
    GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_entry_completion_get_model(completion);
    gchar *item;
    gtk_tree_model_get(model, iter, 0, &item, -1);
    gboolean ans = (atoi(key) % 2 == atoi(item) % 2);
    g_free(item);
    return ans;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget *entry = gtk_entry_new();
    GtkEntryCompletion *completion = gtk_entry_completion_new();
    GtkListStore *ls = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    int i;
    char buf[20];
    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
        gtk_list_store_append(ls, &iter);
        sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
        gtk_list_store_set(ls, &iter, 0, buf, -1);
    }
    gtk_entry_completion_set_model(completion, GTK_TREE_MODEL(ls));
    gtk_entry_completion_set_match_func(completion, (GtkEntryCompletionMatchFunc)func, NULL, NULL);
    gtk_entry_set_completion(GTK_ENTRY(entry), completion);
    gtk_entry_completion_set_text_column(completion, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), entry);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, ace: This is my current approach, the problem is if you fill the completion list with entries without the same prefix, the arrow keys, for example, doesn't work. You need to select with the mouse always.

Comment: @AntonioBeamud I don't seem to see what your problem is. I've edited the answer to include a sample code that I tested, and I can use arrow keys to navigate the completion list even if they don't start with the same prefix. (Here the list contains all numbers which have the same value mod 2).

Comment: I've tested your code and works fine, my problem arises when I update the store, because the rest service I use to complete the list, give me all the data filtered, that's why I'm returning only true in my match func.

Comment: Is it possible to reorder the candidates based on some score value?